# delegate giving error the name 'ad1' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, delegates

> i have created a class person which is having functions add,sub,mul
>   and mytest where i am passing my delegate reference
>
> and in static void main i want if

`DateTime.Now.Hour<12` `it should call add` `if DateTime.Now.Hour<20 it should call sub`.

> but i am getting error

**'ad1' does not exist in current context**

```
 class person
 {
    public void add(int x,int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x+y);
    }
    public void sub(int x,int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x-y);
    }
    public void mul(int x,int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x*y);
    }
    public void test(mydel ad1)
    {
        ad1(2, 3);
    }
 }
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         person p = new person();
         if(DateTime.Now.Hour<12)
         {
             mydel ad1 = p.add;
         }
         else if(DateTime.Now.Hour<20)
         {
             mydel ad1 = p.sub;
         }
         p.test(ad1);      
     }
 }
```

Comment: Just try to move your delegate declaration  `mydel ad1` to line directly after object creation.

Comment: I WANT TO CALL add if hrs<12 and sub if hrs<20

Answer (score 0):

`ad1` is declared inside the `if` block in the `Main` method and doesn't exists outside the `if` scope.

I don't think you need this variable at all just call directly from within the `if`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    person p = new person();
    if(DateTime.Now.Hour<12)
    {
        p.test(p.add);
    }
    else if(DateTime.Now.Hour<20)
    {
        p.test(p.sub);
    }
}
```

This will also ensure that when `Hour` > 20 nothing will be called, and you won't get a null exception.

If you do however choose to use this variable, define it before the `if` (and assign it with `null`) and ensure it's not `null` before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class person
    {
        public void add(int x, int y) => Console.WriteLine(x + y);
        public void sub(int x, int y) => Console.WriteLine(x - y);
        public void mul(int x, int y) => Console.WriteLine(x * y);
        public void test(Action<int, int> ad1) => ad1(2, 3);

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            person p = new person();
            Action<int, int> action = (x, y) => {};
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
            {
                action = p.add;
            }
            else if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 20)
            {
                action = p.sub;
            }
            p.test(action);
        }
    }
```